# How to set variable in array for multi tasking?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, entropy

I want to test this data in both ways `source to destination` and then `destination to source` in Transfer entropy. with this array, I have successfully done `source to destination`. but I want to do both within the same array. as below also showing dataset in two columns.

```
df = pd.read_excel('ardata1.xlsx')
arr = df[['source','dest']].values

#mydata = np.arange(50000).reshape((1000, 10, 5))
#print(arr)
data= arr.reshape((100, 10, 10))
data = Data(data, dim_order='spr')
```

Dataset

```
source      dest
5.702296179 2.916550497
5.375027376 4.104237453
5.285983871 4.037975684
4.603211828 3.332786075
4.957468052 2.439877463
3.973469654 2.877428838
2.982795553 2.799479434
2.092086094 1.794021536
1.60317942  1.403531267
2.815531198 1.413094782
2.899054609 1.42183043
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by 'destination to source'? What should the result look like?

Comment: I dont know what i get the result from that data. i am testing this data to calculate the transfer entropy. i want to do like showing in datasets columns. i want to calculate in both `ways Source to destination` and then `destination to source`. i hope you get my point.

Comment: I think I get it, but it's a math question first, and a programming question later. I have a vague familiarity with transfer entropy - but not more than that.